# Nginx redirecting a specific ID to a specified server

Tags: nginx, networking, nginx-ingress

I have nginx config, part below. In which, depending on the IP block, there is a direction to the server.

```
 location /tts/ {
            
            if ($us_ip) {
    
                    proxy_pass http://192.60.0.99;
    
            }
            if ($eu_ip) {
    
                    proxy_pass http://192.60.0.98;
    
            }
    
            proxy_pass http://192.60.0.95;
    
    }
    location / {
            if ($is_server) {
    
                    proxy_pass https://okg-iii.gliss.com;
            }
    
            proxy_pass https://okg-test.gliss.com;
    
    }
```

I need to redirect a specific request with an ID to a specific server.An example of this path is `/tts/v2/Set?mem_id=100000004E` they go to another server `https://1.1.1.1;`

Like

```
if ($request_uri ~* "/tts/v2/Set?mem_id=100000004E") {
        proxy_pass https://1.1.1.1;
    }
```

But it doesn't work for me. Could you pleae help me? Thnaks.